# How can I "factory reset" my network settings?

Tags: networking, arch-linux, manjaro

I have a strange problem where my laptop running Manjaro experiences a shaking internet connection when connected to a specific network (my home broadband).

It presents like a DNS problem, where it takes a long time to connect, but when it does, the resources load relatively quickly. Same for browser and WGET. Also SSH takes a long time to connect, and once connected will drop out after a short period.

This machine previously worked without issue on this network.

It doesn't matter whether I use cable or wifi, I have the same issue. This same computer is fine when connected to any other network.

Also if I boot to a live Manjaro USB the internet works as expected, so I think it's safe to say it's a configuration issue on this machine (I don't recall changing anything).

So to save me doing a clean install, is there anyway to reset the network and DNS settings or cache?

Thx!!